# Posting JSON data via AJAX to Web API

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm having trouble trying to pass a JSON object via AJAX POST request to Web API.
Here is my AJAX POST request

```
<li><a href="#register">Register</a></li>

$('#usrRegister').click(function () {
    var uname = $('#usrName').val();
    var uloginname = $('#usrLoginName').val();
    var uemail = $('#usrEmail').val();
    var upwd = $('#usrPwd').val();

    var registerObj = {
        "name": uname,
        "username": uloginname,
        "email": uemail,
        "password": upwd
    };
    console.log("registerObj :", registerObj);

    $.ajax({                    
        url: "http://localhost:54118/api/UserApi",
        type: "POST",
        //contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        data: JSON.stringify(registerObj),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Successfully Registered..");
        },
        error: function (xhRequest, ErrorText, thrownError) {
            alert("Failed to process correctly, please try again");
        }
    });
 });
```

**API :**

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post(tblUser userdata)
{
    obj.tblUsers.Add(userdata);
    try
    {
        obj.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException ex)
    {
        foreach (var e in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
        {
            //check the ErrorMessage property
        }
    }
}
```

When I click register it is showing `anonymous function` at `$.ajax({`  in console and API is not calling. But when I  replace contentType with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `application/json` API is calling but showing all fields as null. When I call the same API in REST Client it is working fine. Help me what is causing issue.

Comment: Please share your web api controller class

Comment: are you sure you api is up & running

Comment: why you are stringfying the `JSON.stringify(registerObj)`  instead pass it as : `data: {'userdata',registerObj}`

Comment: @pkhode: Yes,  API is up and running. It's working when I post from Rest Client.

Comment: @pkhode tried but it is going into error function and showing this error in console : **XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:54118/api/UserApi. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400**

Comment: The data should be passed in the following format: `data: {'name' : 'name'}`

Comment: I just checked, I have almost similar ajax cal which is running fine. There are couple of things you should try

Comment: 1)`data : {'userdata' :registerObj }`

2) either set contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", or leave this field

Comment: @N123 property names of your `registerObj ` object doesn't need to be quoted => it's a javascript object. Quoted names is for `JSON`.

Comment: @N123, very imp Did you enable CORS?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for reply. It's working with this code. I have added **`xhrFields: 'withCredentials:true'` and `contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`**

```
         $.ajax({                    
                    url: "http://localhost:54118/api/UserApi",
                    xhrFields: 'withCredentials:true',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                                "name": uname,
                                "username": uloginname,
                                "email": uemail,
                                "password": upwd
                            },
                    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("Successfully Registered..");
                    },
                    error: function (xhRequest, ErrorText, thrownError) {
                        alert("Failed to process correctly, please try again");
                    }
                });
```

Comment: It was the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" bit that did it for me :)

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the `[FromBody]` prefix to your parameter.

Like this:
`public void Post([FromBody] tblUser userdata)`.

Then, you should be able to use `application/json` again!